# Why is my bool return statement returning something other than 0 or 1?

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a bool function that performs some calculations and checks to see if certain conditions are true. If so, it returns true or false, as a bool function should.

However, when it is true, instead of returning 1, it returns random numbers, such as 48, 240, 112, 224, etc.

I'm sure you want the code ... here it is:

```
bool isHappy(int n) {
        if (n < 10) return false;
        
        int sumSquares = 0;
        vector<int> nums;
        string length = to_string(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < length.size()-1; i++) {
            nums.push_back(n % 10);
            if (n >= 10) n = n / 10;
        }   
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            sumSquares += (nums[i] * nums[i]);        
        }
        
        sumSquares += (n * n);

        if (sumSquares == 1) {
          return true; // <--This is the line that seems to cause the problem
        } else {
          isHappy(sumSquares);
        }
    return 0;
    }

int main() {
  int testNumber = 19; 
  cout << isHappy(testNumber);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put a `return` before your `isHappy` call, so all calls that recurse end up returning `0`. Shouldn't cause the problem though. Adding in the `return` makes it impossible to reach the `return 0;` but I think that's okay here; before I add it, it's always returning `0`, after adding `return`, TIO only ever shows a return of `1` though. You're going to need to be more complete (you left off your `#include` and `using` statements so it's not a [MCVE]) and more specific about how you're compiling, with what compiler, etc.

Comment: It should output nothing but 0! Also, as you're `cout`ing a bool, I am guessing this is one of those undefined behaviours, for in C++, `0` is same as `false` and literally any other value is same as `true`

Comment: Can't reproduce.  After including relevant headers and `using namespace std` I get output of zero.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him The "nothing but" part of your comment is too extreme. That phrase suggests that there is more than one test, which suggests going beyond the one test case in the question. If you conduct tests for values other than the given `19`, the output could certainly be something other than `0`. There are not a lot of values that will produce `1`, but there are several (`10`, `100`, `1000`, etc.).

Comment: You annotated one line with "This is the line that seems to cause the problem" -- why do you suspect that line? What observations led you to that conclusion?

Comment: @JaMiT, I agree with the later part of your comment. OP has a `return 0` statement in a bool-returning function, which is unconditionally reached at the end of every call, which indicates that OP is a beginner (and probably thinks just like `main`, every function needs to have a `return 0` at the end).

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him *"and probably thinks just like `main`, every function needs to have a `return 0` at the end"* -- strange that you stuck "just like `main`" in here. Your point would be made without that phrase, so why bring a second misconception in here? (The second misconception is that `main` needs to have a `return 0` at the end, when it does not. Not only could it return a non-zero integer, but also it need not have a `return` statement at all.)

Comment: @JaMiT - While what you say is correct, not all compilers are correct in this sense.   Some compilers - even modern ones - give warnings if any potential paths of execution fall off the end of `main()`.   And, in some cases, there is no way to turn that warning message off (other than adding the unneeded return statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your attempt to implement recursive function is not correct.

```
isHappy(sumSquares);
```

should probably be

```
return isHappy(sumSquares);
```

Comment: It may not be correct, but it wouldn't cause the symptom described.    There is a subsequent `return 0` that is unconditionally reached after a recursive call.

Comment: That wouldn't lead to the result the OP claims to see though. The failure to return the result of the recursive call would just lead to `return 0;` running. It would still only return `true` or `false`, not random numbers.